# Blade templating components?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a input wrapper, (input-wrapper.blade.php)

```
<div class="form-group">
   @yield('input')
</div>
```

Called via:

```
@include('input.checkbox')
```

The checkbox file looks like:

```
@extends('input-wrapper')
@section('input')
<input type="checkbox" value="1">
@endsection
```

The issue I am having is when I call this with multiple inputs (I have one for different input types):

```
 @include('input.checkbox')
 @include('input.textarea')
 ....
```

I just get a rendering of the first item (checkbox) multiple times. i'm hoping to render each type of input.

Comment: Are you sure `input.textarea` is correct and not just a duplicate of .checkbox?

Comment: I am sure that it's unique.